# How to get out of /opt folder using cmd line?

Tags: command-line

I typed `cd /opt` to get into the opt folder. What command should I write to get out of it? `cd..` doesn't work

Comment: try putting a space between `cd` and `..` Also please review http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: If any of the answers below solves your problem, please accept it by clicking the grey check symbol on the left of it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can not get "out" of a folder.

Well, you can, but only by changing to a different directory.

In the terminal, you always have a current working directory. The `cd` command changes this working directory to the specified one.

Running the `cd` command without any arguments brings you back to the default working directory, which is your home directory `/home/USERNAME` (or short `~`).

So probably you just want to go back to the default working directory by simply typing `cd`.

---

However, if by "get out of a folder" you meant to go to the directory one level above in the hierarchy (e.g. from `/usr/bin` to `/usr` or from `/opt` to `/`), this can be achieved by changing to the special directory `..` which always represents the directory a level above.

Note that unlike in Windows/DOS, you may not leave the space between `cd` and `..` out!

```
cd ..
```

Comment: cd .. only goes to parent if you went from parent to current in terminal instance using `./` (or ././ ect)  Otherwise it will just return to $HOME. So `cd /` followed by `cd /opt`  followed by `cd ..`  goes to $HOME where `cd /` followed by `cd ./opt`  followed by `cd .. `goes to /

Comment: @doug Sorry, but what you're saying is plain wrong. `cd ..` *always* changes to the parent directory.

Answer (score 4):

`cd -` will return you to directory where you were before entering `/opt`

Comment: Wow, that's cool! I did not know this yet :)

Answer (score 2):

cd and then the name of the directory that you want, for example

```
cd /etc
```

for /etc or just cd to go to your home directory.

```
cd
```

Looks like you need a space between the "cd" and the ".." in order to go back to the directory above.

Answer (score 1):

To list files and folders

```
ls
```

To step into a folder:

```
cd foldername
```

To one step back:

```
cd ..
```

To home:

```
cd
```